# Regex, match multiples char between two char

Tags: regex

I have some issue with regex.

**Text:**

```
alpha,beta,charlie,"delta delta,delta,",echo
```

**Required output:**

I want to replace the `,` by a blank space if it's inside double quotes `" "`.

```
alpha,beta,charlie,"delta delta delta ",echo
```

I have tried `".*,.*"`, but that matches all the text inside double quotes and not only the `,`

Can someone help ?

Comment: What is your regex falvor/language?

Comment: Without knowing the regex flavor, it is impossible to give the best answer or even a more or less working one.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is hard (or impossible) to do with a single regex.

I'd suggest first matching everything inside the quotes via one regex like `"[^"]*"` and then simply iterate over the matched outputs in your programming language replacing all commas with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this `gnu` solution:

```
gawk -F \" -v OFS=\" '{
 for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {
    gsub(/,/," ",$i);
 }
 print;
}'
```

the test:

```
 printf "alpha,beta,charlie,\"delta delta,delta,\",echo\n" | gawk -F \" -v OFS=\" '{
 for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {
    gsub(/,/," ",$i);
 }
 print;
}'
alpha,beta,charlie,"delta delta delta ",echo
```